# $mysqli->prepare with SQL Transactions

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, transactions

I am pretty new to SQL Transactions and tried to execute following statement which did unfortunately not work...

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("

BEGIN;

INSERT INTO groups (group_name, group_desc, user_id_fk) VALUES ("'.$groupName.'","'.$groupDesc.'","'.$user_id.'");

INSERT INTO group_users (group_id_fk, user_id_fk) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), "'.$username.'");

COMMIT;

") or trigger_error($mysqli->error, E_USER_ERROR);

$stmt->execute();

$stmt->close();
```

Is this even possible what I am trying here or is it completely wrong?

I appreciate every response, thank you!

Comment: Please describe "did not work".

Comment: well, I am getting a blank screen after submitting the form...
Nevertheless, my initial question remains, as if this statement is even possible to submit via this function?

Comment: Where are you binding your parameters?

Answer (score 0):

You are using prepare() wrong way. There is absolutely no point in using prepare() if you are adding variables directly in the query.

This is how your queries have to be executed:

```
$mysqli->query("BEGIN");

$sql = "INSERT INTO groups (group_name, group_desc, user_id_fk) VALUES (?,?,?)";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("ssi",$groupName,$groupDesc,$user_id);
$stmt->execute();

$sql = "INSERT INTO group_users (group_id_fk, user_id_fk) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), ?)";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s",$username);
$stmt->execute();

$mysqli->query("COMMIT");
```